# Magento 2 Most view product collection return 0

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 Most view product collection return 0 but in database i have data

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $_productsFactory;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
      \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
       array $data = []
   ) {
       $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
       $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
       $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }
    public function getCollection(){
            $currentStoreId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $collection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addViewsCount()->setStoreId(
                    $currentStoreId
            )->addStoreFilter(
                    $currentStoreId
            );
            $items = $collection->getItems();
            return $collection;
        }
```

**phtml**

```
<?php
    $items = $block->getCollection();
    echo count($items);
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo $item->getName() .'<br/>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: Every things seems okay , Have you get proper store id ? sample data is installed or not ?

Comment: $items should return rather than $collection

Comment: YEs in table also data is there

Comment: also in my dashboard also most view tab We couldn't find any records.

Comment: Need to check bro , not an idea.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento 2 shows the most viewed product in  Magento Admin > DASHBOARD > choose tab Most Viewed Products.

The _prepareCollection() method in vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Tab/Products/Viewed.php is used for getting products collection.

So you may use the same code in your module's block. And in phtml file you need to write the below code-

```
<?php
$items = $this->getCollection();
foreach($items as $item)
{
    echo $item->getName() .'<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I used same only still same problem